# How can I send a message in telegram with APScheduler and Aiogram

Tags: python, apscheduler, aiogram, sqlite3-python

I've tried to do this:

```
sched = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone='Europe/Moscow')
sched.add_jobstore(SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///ProjectDB.sqlite'))
sched.add_job(create_note, 'interval', seconds=5, kwargs={'bot': bot, 'id':id})
```

with function:

```
async def create_note(bot: Bot, id):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=id, text='some text')
```

But I got this: `TypeError: cannot pickle 'SSLContext' object`

Comment: Also, tried to put `add_job` into message_handler, but got this: `cannot pickle '_asyncio.Future' object`